# Button inside collection view not highlighting on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, uicollectionview

I have a button inside a collection view, but unlike my other buttons around the app, this one doesn't highlight when you tap it. I have tried a few things that were suggested such as turning on Shows Touch on Highlight on the button, and setting delaysContentTouches to false.

```
func createCollectionView() {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)

        cv = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, view.frame.width, 250);
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cvCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //suggested on other SO answers:
        cv.delaysContentTouches = false

        for view in cv.subviews {
            if view is UIScrollView {
                (view as? UIScrollView)!.delaysContentTouches = false
                break
            }
        }
    } 


//Button:
var onTap: ((cvCell) -> Void)?
    @IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
        onTap?(self)
    }

//CollectionView select:
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cvCell
  cell.btn.setTitle("follow", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add button code also which is no highlighted.

Comment: Try, you can set highlighted image in  your button

Comment: All my other buttons in the app are highlighting fine though without any extra code. Any idea why it's not behaving right here?

Comment: at where tapped this action ?

Comment: Figured it out. I had to do this: cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false

Answer (score 1):

If your button type is  `cell.btn.buttonType == UIButtonType.system` than it's Highlighted effect on button title display automatically. otherwise `cell.btn.buttonType == UIButtonType.custom` than you need to give your own Highlighted effect.

[image]